# Connect to Azure Cosmos DB's API for MongoDB with Python error in Concierge Subscription

Tags: mongodb, azure, pymongo, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I am following the tutorial [Quickstart: Build a Python app using Azure Cosmos DB's API for MongoDB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/create-mongodb-flask#review-the-code) and I have successfully gone through deploying a database and the app on the Azure Cosmos DB Emulator. Then I create a concierge subscription to proceed to the next step "Create a database account" and on step "Update your connection string" on my code:

```
client = MongoClient(connectionString)
db = client.client1
db.authenticate(name, password)
```

I get this error: `Exception has occurred: ServerSelectionTimeoutError deployment1-chris.mongo.cosmos.azure.com:10255: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it File "C:\Users\chxe\git-samples\databaseStructure\dbCreation.py", line 62, in <module> db.authenticate(name, password)`
I follow the instructions adding the primary connection string usernames and passwords but I am not able to connect.
Anyone some ideas on that?

Comment: concierge subscription? wut is that?

Comment: It is the one you create when you do the exercises for Azure Cosmo [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/create-cosmos-db-for-scale/2-create-an-account) where you open a sandbox for some hours and use it temporarily.

Comment: I have seen similar problems connecting to CosmosDB's MongoDB API without ssl=true in a connection string. Do you have it?